# Repeat text occurs as output when executing array sorting

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

When sorting an array, the only problem I'm experiencing is that the output text is being printed for every number in the array, and not just once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
#define ARRAYSIZE 10    

using namespace std;

int main(){
int myArray[ARRAYSIZE];     
int *myPtr; 
srand(time(NULL));      
myPtr = myArray;            

for (int count = 0; count < ARRAYSIZE; count++)
{
    *myPtr = rand() % 100 + 1;  
    myPtr++;
    cout << "Array before being sorted: " << myArray[count] << endl;
}

for (int count = 0; count < ARRAYSIZE; count++)
{
    sort(myArray, myArray + ARRAYSIZE);
    cout << "Array after being sorted: " << myArray[count] << endl;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Using the above code, it would output something like:

> Array before being sorted: 57
>   Array before being sorted: 88
>   Array before being sorted: 59
>   Array before being sorted: 18
>   Array before being sorted: 34
>   Array before being sorted: 82
>   Array before being sorted: 65
>   Array before being sorted: 77
>   Array before being sorted: 47
>   Array before being sorted: 71

When I am attempting to get something like this:

> Array before being sorted: 57 88 59 18 34 82 65 77 47 71

The same exact thing occurs for the second 'for' statement, where it produces "Array after being sorted: " for every number in the array.

I don't know how to change this, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the `cout` before the for loop

```
cout << "Array before being sorted: " ;
for (int count = 0; count < ARRAYSIZE; count++)
{
    *myPtr = rand() % 100 + 1;  
    myPtr++;
    cout << myArray[count] << " ";
}
cout<<endl;
```

And call the sort function outside the loop

```
sort(myArray, myArray + ARRAYSIZE);
cout << "Array after being sorted: "
for (int count = 0; count < ARRAYSIZE; count++)
{        
  cout << myArray[count] <<" ";
}
```

Comment: Your above suggestions worked to remove the repeat text, however I was wondering if it was possible to make the output numbers all appear on the same line like so: "Array (before/after) being sorted: 10 14 16 27 59", instead of how each number of the array has its own line.

Comment: @cyntrix I've updated the answer. It prints in one line only. I've removed the `endl` and addedd `" "` (space)

Comment: Sorry, was a bit too hasty. Works perfectly, thank you!